# Can Acid Darts critical hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

Can a wizard (conjuration school) critical hit with the level 1 school ability Acid Dart? And is all critical damage acid-typed too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes and yes**

[Acid Dart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/sean-k-reynolds-games/acid-dart)

> You fire a small dart made of acid at the target. **You must succeed on a ranged touch attack to hit your target.** The dart deals 1d3 points of acid damage.

[Critical Hits on the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Critical-Hits)

> Spells and Critical Hits
>
> A spell that requires an attack roll can score a critical hit. A spell attack that requires no attack roll cannot score a critical hit. If a spell causes ability damage or drain (see Special Abilities), the damage or drain is doubled on a critical hit.

It doesn't mention anywhere that the damage from the critical hit is a different type; it simply deals double damage. So all damage remains of the same type.

Comment: The school ability does more damage then the cantrip fwiw